# wp_redirect is not saving in functions.php depending on placement

Tags: wordpress

I am adding some code in functions.php (in the wordpress Theme Editor hosted in wp engine) and depending on where I place wp_redirect, it will save or not save

Example: It will save when I do this

```
add_action('template_redirect','test_template');

//this one saves fine
function test_template() {
    global $wp_query;
    $userId = $wp_query->get( 'userId', NULL );
    $url = get_site_url();
    if ( NULL !== $userId ) {
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit;
    }
}

//However, when I do this I get: "Unable to communicate back with site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP."

function test_template() {
    global $wp_query;
    $userId = $wp_query->get( 'userId', NULL );
    $url = get_site_url();
    wp_redirect($url);
    exit;
}
```

Not sure why the second function will not save, any ideas?

Comment: Where are you trying to save it to? Local? A server? Who's your host? We need more info.

Comment: In the Theme editor  (and the file is functions.php)

Comment: Sure, but is this a local environment, or are you doing this on a web server?

Comment: Yes, it is hosted in wp engine - I am using the wordpress Theme Editor to update functions.php (under Appearance > Theme Editor) and clicking Update File

Comment: WPEngine, as you may know, has PHP code sniffing to find errors. I don't necessarily see an error in your second block. Do you not have SFTP access? Why you are unsatisfied with your first block that has a catch to make sure the redirect only happens if the `$userId` isn't NULL?

Comment: I have a lot more code I want to add, but just giving a minimal case to show the issue. Ultimately I want the redirect and exit at the end so I can do any processing I want to before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is triggering a infinite redirect loop. According to WordPress Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

> This action hook executes just before WordPress determines which template page to load

This means that it will run every time before loading a page template. So basicaly after wp_redirect($url) the action template_redirect will be hooked and will redirect again.